# Efficient replace of nan/na values in xts object

Tags: r, xts

I have an object that has 20k columns. I want to replace all occurence of `NaN`, `NA`, and say a specific value with 0. How do i do that:

Subset of data:

```
           AAC-200004 AACB-200708 AACE-200610   BVX BWL.A BZC   BZM CAK  CANF   CAW CCA CCF   CEF CET CEV   CFD CFP  CH CIK
2015-04-09         NA          NA          NA 0.000 0.000   0 0.000   0 0.333 0.333   0   0 0.333   0   0 0.000   0   0   0
2015-04-10         NA          NA          NA   NaN   NaN NaN   NaN NaN   NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2015-04-13         NA          NA          NA 0.000 0.000   0 0.333   0 0.333 0.000   0   0 0.000   0   0 0.333   0   0   0
2015-04-14         NA          NA          NA   NaN   NaN NaN   NaN NaN   NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2015-04-15         NA          NA          NA 0.333 0.333   0 0.000   0 0.333 0.000   0   0 0.000   0   0 0.000   0   0   0
2015-04-16         NA          NA          NA   NaN   NaN NaN   NaN NaN   NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

`zoo` has a `na.fill` function and I can use that. thought i'd ask that too not knowing if there are more faster ways of doing it.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
coredata(sample.xts)[is.na(sample.xts) | is.nan(sample.xts)] <- 0
```

Comment: @akrun, true. I'll leave my approach as is because while your comment works in one direction--(`is.na` captures `NaN` values too)--it doesn't work in the reverse--(`is.nan` does not capture `NA` values).